# iPhone: how to make a fat library containing armv7s support?

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, armv7, armv6

I have external libraries for `armv6, armv7, i386 and armv7s`. When I try to put all together using lipo, I got an error message like so, saying `armv7s` isn't supported:

```
lipo: known architecture flags are: any little big ppc64 x86_64 ppc970-64 ppc i386 m68k hppa sparc m88k i860 veo arm ppc601 ppc603 ppc603e ppc603ev ppc604 ppc604e ppc750 ppc7400 ppc7450 ppc970 i486 i486SX pentium i586 pentpro i686 pentIIm3 pentIIm5 pentium4 m68030 m68040 hppa7100LC veo1 veo2 veo3 veo4 armv4t armv5 xscale armv6 armv7 armv7f armv7k
```

How to solve this problem?

Comment: As suggested by H2CO3, I've just updated my lipo tool and it recognized the armv7s architecture. I hope this helps someone else. Thanks for your answers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are possibly trying to use an older version of lipo that does not support armv7s. You should try that with the lipo version bundled with Xcode 4.5.

Comment: I'm downloading the new Command Line Tools, from the Downloads option in XCode to give it a try and I'll let you know the results. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You would need the sources and compile it with `armv7s` support. Also, `armv7` should work just fine on the `armv7s` devices too.

Comment: Good! I already have it compiled for armv7, so I'm good to go for armv7s, right?

Comment: If you need it to run specifically for `armv7s`, you need to compile the source for `armv7s`. If you're simply looking to run it on iPhone 5, `armv7` should work just fine. You can simply remove the `armv7s` from the Valid Architectures in your build settings. The code should work just fine.

Comment: I have a separate library compiled for armv7 and another for armv7s. Would just the armv7 suffice?

Comment: If they do the same thing, yes.